# Can I get rid of <layout>legacy</layout> in depenency in pom.xml?

Tags: maven

the problem is like below.

```
No connector available to access repository maven-repository.java.net (
http://download.java.net/maven/1) of type legacy using the available factories 
WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]
```

As many people says on the internet, I deleted the folder in m2 repository. 
but it didn't work and I spent a lot of time solving this.
Finally, I found the part " legacy  " in pom.xml and it can't be applied in maven3. So I got rid of it. So it did work.

But I'm wondering if it is ok or not.
please let me know. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maven3 doesn't support maven1 repository any longer.

If you want to works with maven1 repository and maven3, you'd better use a repository manager like nexus or artifactory.

See also:
https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-LegacystyleRepositories

Comment: I understood, I just got rid of <layout> tag and then it works. Is it ok?